# Google Data API on Symbian

Tags: python, symbian, google-data-api, pys60

I want to use Google Data API on a Symbian device with pys60 but I couldn't find any doc.
Is there any way to install Google Data APIs Python Client Library on Symbian ?

Comment: Have you found any info on this question? If you have, please share!

Comment: You are right,the Symbian part of the question is the problem and I haven't found any answer yet for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Data API protocol documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html), even the client libraries are basically just sending XML data over HTTP, so it should be possible (in theory, at least) to send the same data from your own PyS60 application by grokking the code of the Python client. If memory serves me right, ElementTree is included in Python 2.5, and should by extension, be in PyS60. It's the only required dependency for the Python client library.

Answer (score 0):

Google Data Api is just a bunch of interpreted Python code. It should run in any Python 2.2 interpreter after you download it from the [project page](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/). It has a [nice tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/python_client_lib.html).

Maybe you want to know [how to install downloaded Python packages](http://docs.python.org/install/).

Comment: I'm not sure it's that simple on a Symbian device. Have you actually tried it? There's no command line (so how would you call `python setup.py`?). I guess you can just put the files somewhere and edit `sys.path`, but these environments are pretty limited and sandboxed. In other words, the Symbian part of the question is the problem, not the Python part.